# Check if Android is presenting its screen

Tags: android

Does anybody know if there is a generic way to check if the screen is currently being presented, e.g. via Miracast, Chromecast or any other app?

My app runs in the background and shows notifications every now and then. I'd like to avoid that while the screen is visible to others.